# Notepad++ regex to find Nth instance of a space character on a line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to match only the nth (let's say 5th) whitespace character on a line and then replace that space with a line break (so that all my lines essentially have no more than 4 words / 4 spaces). On the REPLACE line in Notepad++, I think an \r\n would generally do the trick, and it is just the FIND pattern that is giving me problems.

I know there is a relatively simple regex solution for this that I am blanking on, but in my searches of "Find Nth instance of pattern on a line" type regex answers, the regex that has been closest to what I want is also matching everything before that 5th whitespace on a line. Here is that code that is grabbing too much.

```
^(?:\S+\s){5}
```

I know the "\S+" probably should not be there, but my attempts to pair this code down to some basic variations on this below

```
^(\s){5}
```

have all failed one way or another.

So here is what the text result of the regex should be.

FROM:

```
This line is too long. I want to shorten it.

This line is too long. I would really like to know why my regex is not working.
```

TO:

```
This line is too long. 

I want to shorten it.

This line is too long.

I would really like to

know why my regex is

not working.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex in find:

`((?:\S+\s){4}\S+)\s`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dYlhol/2)

Then replace it with `\1\r\n`.

This essentially captures everything up to the 5th space and then replaces it with the first capture group (`\1`) followed by `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with not preserving existing line breaks, then a simple solution to this would be to do two separate replacements like this:

First, search for `\s+` and Replace All with a single space.

Then do this replacement:

Find what:

```
(\S+ \S+ \S+ \S+ \S+)\s
```

Do a "Replace All" with:

```
$1\r\n
```